# Is it possible to change the NetBIOS Uppercase and Lowercase letters?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

During the domain setup process we accidentally put the NetNIOS as **OURCOMPANY**.

the management requested us to make it as **OurCompany** instead.

is that possible or we need to reinstall everything again!

Comment: we need to separate two things domain and netbios.......... domain name possible but aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa lot of work ahead of you (i would rather create brand new one...). And there's netbios...... Why people still using it???????? none and I mean literally NONE new software 2k>>>>>> is depending on it, for god sake even microsoft stopped using netbios after windows NT so why use it? don't you have separated DNS? (unless your company is using still windows NT in some places or software which depends on netbios....... then just remove it uncheck box make it domain wide with gpo and that's it

Comment: Thanks michal for your comment and clarification 

Our Domain Name is fine "OurCompany", I agree with you about the  NetBIOS. we do not have any 2k OS or so, I guess we will talk to our management to clarify the thing up.

Thanks

Comment: I meant we are not using any pre windows 2000 applications or so!

Answer (score 2):

1. NetBIOS names are case aware but case insensitive.
2. NetBIOS names are represented in upper case regardless of actual case.
3. It isn't possible to specifiy the NetBIOS name in anything other than upper case. During the DCPROMO process (using the advanced installation mode) typing the NetBIOS name in anything other than uppercase will always result in the name being uppercase.

So in short, it isn't possible to rename the NetBIOS name in mixed case.

Comment: One of our client's ADDS NetBIOS domain names is in camel case so it can be done.

Comment: Well, I could be wrong but I've never seen it and have never been able to create the NetBIOS domain name in anything other than upper case. Are you referring to the domain name or to a computer name?

Comment: Here's an example of one of our Active Directory Domain Services' NetBIOS domain names shown on the logon screen: http://i.imgur.com/K3NvzCs.png

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps for using RENDOM, however, you may choose to reinstall.

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2015/05/step-by-step-guide-to-rename-active-directory-domain-name/

Answer (score 0):

Following Microsoft's guide you can't go wrong (or at least that's the theory). No need to reinstall. Just go ahead and rename. It involves installing a tool, and going through a number of steps, but it is not difficult. Much quicker than reinstalling.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794907(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: It is relevant to 2012 R2.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781575(v=ws.10).aspx